# "Fake pagination and VueJS"

Tags: pagination, vuejs2

I would like (for the moment) to implement what I call a fake pagination.

I have a table that is populated with a bunch of data. I get the whole data set with AJAX but the table is big.

My question is : How can I implement someting to display the first 10 items of my table then if I click on page 2 it is going to take the item from 11 to 21 and so on...

```
<!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns"
          @click="sortBy(key)"
          :class="{ active: sortKey == key }">
          {{ key | capitalize }}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="entry in filteredData">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid
    :data="gridData"
    :columns="gridColumns"
    :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
</div>



// register the grid component
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function () {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function () {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var data = this.data
      if (filterKey) {
        data = data.filter(function (row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        data = data.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return data
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function (str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
      { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
      { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },
         { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },
            { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },
               { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },   { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 },

    ]
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r89fy3vn/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create a numeric property called page to pass to the component (first page = 0, etc.), and then change the component template to

```
<tr v-for="entry in filteredData.slice(page*10, 10)">
```

There's certainly some refinement to do with error checking the bounds of the page variable, etc., but this should be a good start.